# Matching Strings With Regex

Tags: regex, string, matching

I'm creating a little text editor for editing Python scripts and I'm having trouble with a couple `regex expressions`.

For strings, I have:

```
\".*\"
```

A couple of things wrong with this... first of all, it will only match the string if it has both a starting quote and an ending quote. So, say I start typing out some code and when I type:

```
x = "Hello World
```

the `regex` won't detect the string because it doesn't have its ending quote. The next problem is it won't work with the backslash. So if I type:

```
x = "\"I'm leaving in an hour\""
```

the `regex` won't match the text (I'm leaving in an hour) because it's set off by the quotes. Do you get what I'm saying?

The next `regex` I need is kind of simple I just don't know how to write it.

I need to match the text after a specific word like 'def' and end at a character that is not a letter, number, or underscore. So if I have:

```
def helloWorld(self)
```

I want to match `'helloWorld'` and leave everything else out.

So if you could help me out with any of these that'd be great.

(Some example source code here http://newspawn.org/texteditor.py)
Requires Python 3.3 and PyQt5

Comment: What programming language are you using for creating text editor?

Comment: Python. I have a program written entirely in Python and it's compiled with the Python interpreter built in. So users can code custom scripts for it and run them in it directly. All I have left to build is the text editor

Comment: Are you coding Python editor written in Python?

Comment: Yes, it's all completely in Python

Comment: If possible, upload your code somewhere like [gists](https://gist.github.com/) so that everyone can know what you are implementing.

Comment: I uploaded it to my server http://newspawn.org/texteditor.py

Answer (score 0):

For your second one, you want a lookbehind:

```
(?<=def )\w*
```

For part b of your first one (escaped strings), a simple way to do it is to first remove all escaped quotes and store the result into a temporary variable, then match for strings on that.

Comment: thats a lookbehind btw

Comment: For part 1 of the first question, you can make the trailing quote optional using `\".*\"?` Since .* is greedy, use `\"[^\"]*\"?`

Comment: \"[^\"]*\"? works with getting the quotes, but won't get the text within. Removing the question mark gets the text within, but then I'm back to the same problem with it requiring both quotes to find it. Do I use it exactly as givin or do I need to change something in it?